# How to use a Popup binded to a ToggleButton inside a ListView in xaml wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a list of ToggleButtons. Each of them is binded to a popup.
I had a problem with that, so I tried to put everything inside a StackPanel.
But, now, when the app is running, it shows an empty space (for the Popup) right after the ToggleButton. What can I do to solve that?

I've just added two images:
The first one is when the page is being uploaded.
The second one is when I scroll down the page.

[image]
[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="ListOfRecipes" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="25,0.333,25,35" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Grid.RowSpan="5" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="RecipeButton" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FF65C365" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Height="150" Width="328" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="128" Width="328">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="128" Width="128" Margin="0,6,0,-5.667" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="128" Width="192">
                                <TextBlock Height="25" Width="190" Foreground="#FF6FDC13" Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <Image Name="YesOrNoImage" Source="{Binding Path=YesOrNoImage}" Width="102" Height="102" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RecipeButton, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="514" Width="328" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="PopupOne" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.RowSpan="4" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" IsHoldingEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF65C365" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Height="514" Width="328">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="328" Width="328" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF6FDC13" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" />
                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding RecipeText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="18" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Comment: replace `StackPanel` with a `Grid`

Comment: I've tried this too. Same problem.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of that "empty space"?

Comment: OK, I've just added two images..

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the issue is caused by the `<PopUp Height=514/>`
To test it, set the height to 0 to see if it fixes the gap. If so, you can bind the visibility to `PopUp.IsOpen` using a Visibility converter (I think Blue MVVM has one). Since I'm not very educated on Converters at the moment, I came up with a workaround.

```
public RecipeButton : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   // Need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged logic on IsCheckedVisiblity for UI to be notified of visibility changes
   public Visibility IsCheckedVisibility { get; set; }
   private bool _IsChecked;
   public bool IsChecked {
      get { return _IsChecked };
      set { _IsChecked = value;
            this.IsCheckedVisibility = value == true ? Visiblity.Collapsed : Visiblity.Visible;
      }

}
```

`<PopUp Visibility = "{Binding IsCheckedVisibility}"/>`

Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll try something else.

Comment: OMG! Perfect! Thank you so much!!!!! I've just changed the height to 0 and it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I want to vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet =] Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!! =]

Comment: No problem, mate. Good luck on your app!

Comment: Hi again =] Could you help me please with another question I asked? =] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067422/how-to-define-the-height-of-a-popup-to-be-different-from-the-button-height-in-a