# How to define the Location of a Popup to be different from the Button Location in a ListView? XAML C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView of ToggleButtons. Every button is binded to a Popup window.
Every Popup window is being opened at the same place as the button, but I want it to be at the same place as the *first* button.
Here is the code and images:

The buttons:
[image]

This is what happens when the first button is open:
[image]

This is what happens when the second button is open:
[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="ListOfRecipes" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="25,0.333,25,35" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Grid.RowSpan="5" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="150*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="RecipeButton" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FF65C365" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Height="150" Width="328" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="128" Width="328">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="128" Width="128" Margin="0,6,0,-5.667" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="128" Width="192">
                                <TextBlock Height="25" Width="190" Foreground="#FF6FDC13" Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <Image Name="YesOrNoImage" Source="{Binding Path=YesOrNoImage}" Width="102" Height="102" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RecipeButton, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="0" Width="328" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="PopupOne" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" IsHoldingEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RecipeButton}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF65C365" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Height="514" Width="328">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="328" Width="328" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF6FDC13" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" />
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding RecipeText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="18" />
                        </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>

                        </Border>
                </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I'll try and allocate some time to check it out after work.

Answer (score 0):

In the popup you can define a grid and set the popup height there
Something like this:

```
<Popup x:Name="resultsPopup"
                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                       IsOpen="{Binding IsResultsPopupOpen,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Placement="Bottom"
                       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}"
                       StaysOpen="False">
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                          ElementName=SearchBox}"
                          Height="300">


                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can place the popup wherever you want with the Placement property as shown above, the set the binding of the "PlacementTarget" to the control you want to bind.
In the example above the popup will be shown below the UI control named SearchBox

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I didn't mean the height of the Popup is wrong. I meant that I want the Popup to start at the top of the page and not at the height of the button.